# Increasing stack size of an .net exe

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, stack-overflow

I get a stack overflow exception and it is for this specific case only. I can see about `EDITBIN.EXE /STACK:<s..` but can i do this in any way in a PC without Visual studio.
I am trying to give an workaround for my user - so that he can work with the app till i fix it in code..

Comment: Can't you patch the exe on your machine and give the patched exe to the user? Also normally stackoverflow exceptions come from code that go in infinite recursion. So increasing the stack size may not help.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant try that.. if i run EditBin.exe against a exe built in release - it updates the exe file..?

Comment: Also 'Editbin.exe' is a standalone exe..?

Comment: EditBin.exe is meant to update the binary file. Can you elaborate on your need here? Are you NOT allowed to update the exe? If yes, then why?

Comment: i am able to use Editbin.exe and increase stack size and resolve my stackoverflow issue., if it standalone - i thought of taking this Editbin.exe to user's pc and run it there..

Comment: Editbin needs some VC dlls present in WinSxS folder + some dlls placed in the same folder as it is. Hence, It would be easier for you to copy the exe from customer's machine to your machine, patch it and give it back to the user (keep a backup of the original exe)

Answer (score -1):

You might find an answer with this : ( http://www.justanswer.com/computer/38rvx-increase-stack-size-win7.html ). But, seems to be specific for "no_more irp stack locations"...

> Expert's Answer
>
> Click Start, type regedit, and then press enter on the keyboard.
>   Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Mup\Parameters In
>   the right pane, right-click DfsIrpStackSize, and then click Modify.
>
> Note If the DfsIrpStackSize registry entry does not exist, you must
>   create it. To do this, follow these steps: On the Edit menu, point to
>   New, and then click DWORD Value.  Type DfsIrpStackSize, and then press
>   ENTER.  In the Base box, click Decimal, type 10 in the Value data box,
>   and then click OK. Exit Registry Editor. Restart the computer.
>
> You can bookmark or favorite this page and then use that bookmark to
>   get back to me. Take all the time that you need in order to test this.